# Finding LBA to PBA mapping table

Tags: c, linux, mapping, solid-state-drive

I have installed a virtual open channel SSD on qemu and am trying to figure the LBA and the corresponding PBA mapping.

I have already gone through different documentation and successfully found the LBA for any file through fibmap API.

However, to find the physical address mapped on the SSD I have to use PBLK where I can find the L2P_MAP. Unfortunately, I can't find that file since it's never generated by my PBLK instance. I am not really sure what's the problem.

My question is : Is there any way to find this LBA to PBA mapping with/without using PBLK?

I would really appreciate any help or suggestion.
Thank you